# Deno oak error: Uncaught AssertionError: Unexpected skip of the emit

Tags: javascript, deno, oak

I am getting error when trying to run simple `Deno Js` `OAK` middleware server on my:

```
Ubuntu 18.04, 
Deno 1.0.4, 
v8 8.4.300, 
typescript 3.9.2
```

By running either  `deno run index.js`  or running `deno run -A index.js`

```
$ deno run index.js
Compile file:///home/some/tst/index.js
error: Uncaught AssertionError: Unexpected skip of the emit.
    at Object.assert ($deno$/util.ts:33:11)
    at compile ($deno$/compiler.ts:1170:7)
    at tsCompilerOnMessage ($deno$/compiler.ts:1338:22)
    at workerMessageRecvCallback ($deno$/runtime_worker.ts:72:33)
    at file:///home/some/dcode/tst/__anonymous__:1:1
```

This is my index.js file code:

```
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";

const app = new Application();

app.use((ctx) => {
  ctx.response.body = "Hello World!";
});

await app.listen({ port: 8000 });
```

Comment: Can it help? https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/4298

Comment: FYI: Deno already uses the `deno` tag, creating the `denojs` adds nothing.

Comment: Thanks @NikitaMadeev I already checked that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Change the file type from .js to .ts.**

I was introducing me in Deno with the "complex program" in its Getting started section and I was unable to run the program until I had change the file type from javascript to typescript. I hope have helped you!

Comment: Thank you very much I just renamed my index.js to .ts and it's running!

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue introduced in `v1.0.3` or `v1.0.4`: https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/6082 and it's still happening in `1.0.5`

Until it's fixed, the solution is to downgrade Deno to `1.0.0` and use Oak `4.0.0`, which is the appropriate Oak version for that Deno version.

```
import { Application } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak@v4.0.0/mod.ts'
```

---

To downgrade Deno, you can do the [following](https://deno.land/x/install/):

```
curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | sh -s v1.0.0
```

or if you're using Windows:

```
$v="1.0.0"; iwr https://deno.land/x/install/install.ps1 -useb | iex
```

Comment: Your answer was solution. I had to  downgrade and tested all versions from v1.0.1,v1.0.2, v1.0.3,v1.0.4, v1.0.5 latest it works on is v1.0.3 with oak@v4.0.0.  Thank you!  Note: I used deno version manager to install all these verison https://github.com/axetroy/dvm